# material autocomplete closes bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I've implemented a very simple material auto complete.

And using Angular 5, with a bootstrap 4 dropdown to display a form

What I'm finding is when I put the autocomplete, into the dropdown and select an item within for the autocomplete, it closes the entire dropdown.

The autocomplete itself, works as intended

Html:

```
 <div class="btn-filter">
<button class="btn" id="user-filter" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Filter <span class="ion-levels"></span></button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id='dClose' aria-labelledby="user-filter" style="width: 400px; height: 300px">
      <form class="example-form">
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="State" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.name">
                <img style="vertical-align:middle;" aria-hidden src="{{state.flag}}" height="25" />
                <span>{{ state.name }}</span> |
                <small>Population: {{state.population}}</small>
              </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
          </mat-form-field>
      </form>
  </div>
```

Typescript/Javascript, for the autocomplete:

```
  constructor() {
    this.stateCtrl = new FormControl();
        this.filteredStates = this.stateCtrl.valueChanges
          .pipe(
            startWith(''),
            map(state => state ? this.filterStates(state) : this.states.slice())
          );
      }

      filterStates(name: string) {
        return this.states.filter(state =>
          state.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0);
      }
```

This is just for testing purposes and I know not best practices, but I set a time out in the ngAfterViewInit

```
   ngAfterViewInit() {
        setTimeout(()=>{
                document.getElementById('dClose').addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
                  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                });//this works, when the actual dropdown itself is clicked it does not close
                document.getElementById('dClose').addEventListener('onblur', (e)=>{
                  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                });//this does not work, when the autocomplete is selected, the dropdown closes
            }, 3000)
      }
```

Any ideas are appreciated

Comment: Could you add your code?

Comment: the autoomplete attribute for a select element is invalid HTML (https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120320/select.html#select)

Comment: thanks for your replies I've updated the question, which should shed more light on the situation, if you'd like me to provide the full code, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to access autocomplete [MatAutocompleteTrigger](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#MatAutocompleteTrigger). It has openPanel method. And it's better to use Angular's @Viewchild instead of document.getElementById...

**Component class:**

```
  import { MatAutocompleteTrigger } from '@angular/material';
  ...    
  @ViewChild(MatAutocompleteTrigger) autoTrigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
  ...
  onSelect(): void { setTimeout(() => {this.autoTrigger.openPanel()}, 10)}
```

**Component template**

```
   <mat-autocomplete " (optionSelected)="onSelect() ...>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-edxs2n)**

Comment: This does not work and from what I read from the docs the function that is executed keeps the panel for the auto complete open, what I want to do is keep the bootstrap dropdown open ".dropdown-menu"